Busqueda de caracteres en una celda EXCEL
Busco una formula que me diga si una cadena de caracteres contiene unas letras concretas. Por ejemplo. Con una celda que contiene "HoyL1-25" uso esta formula.
=SI(CONTAR.SI(E13;"*L1*");"Contiene valor";"No lo contiene")

Esta me sirve pero si la celda en cuestión contiene "HoyL10000-25" tambien me devuelve busqueda positiva. Tengo que acotarlo a la busqueda exacta del texto L1.
Gracias.

¿Y si sacas los astericos y lo dejas en CONTAR.SI(E13;"L1")?

Tienes que dejar claro por qué HoyL1-25 sí es válido y por qué HoyL10000-25 no. En ambos casos se cumple lo qué dices de contener L1. Si eres capaz de definir eso podemos ayudarte con la fórmula. Tiene pinta de lo que buscas en realidad es L1- (acabado en guión) pero quien lo sabe eres tú
